# Simple jsfiddle example with dojo 1.8 not working

Tags: dojo, jsfiddle

What is wrong with this simple jsfiddle example using dojo 1.8: http://jsfiddle.net/ractive/qKW2G/3/

The button widget is not loaded on startup, although parseOnLoad is set to true in the data-dojo-config attribute:

```
data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run with `async: true`, then you need to include the parser and button in the require.

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dijit/form/Button"], 
  function(parser, on, dom) {
    ...
});​
```

If you run with `async: false`, then parser and the widgets will be required automatically.

Comment: But how can I set it up to use async mode and do the auto requiring as [this test here](http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojo/trunk/tests/parser/parseOnLoadAutoRequire.html) shows?